# Opening modal from modal, form won't submit

Tags: javascript, asp.net, modal-dialog

I'm trying to figure this out, I have a modal with the login inputs, and a link that refers to a second modal, in case the user wants to register.

Both modals depends on the same form (asp.net master page), and all the inputs have a required filed validator.

The thing is, when I open the second modal, I can't submit the form, because it detects the user/pass pass inputs from the first modal as empty and won't validate.

Is there any way to remove those inputs from codebehind or JS when clicking
`<a href="#Div1" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="myModal">Register now</a>`
or 
`<button ID="bnt" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Div1">Register now</button>`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using asp.net WebForms not asp.net MVC (since you mentioned MasterPage not layout page!).

Use different ValidationGroup for registration form. So when you click register button, it won't trigger validations of login fields.

```
<asp:Button ValidationGroup="Register"...>Register</asp:Button>
```

and modify validators for those registration fields to have same "Register" validation group..

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't focusing right the issue, quite simply and effecty answer